# How to make IObservable.ToEnumerable non blocking / not consume the entire source before returning?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How can I get ToEnumerable to not complete the `test()` before returning?

```
 IObservable<string> str =
        test()
        .ToObservable()
        .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("obs done"));

 int i = 0;
 foreach (string s in str.ToEnumerable())
 {
    if (i++ > 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("break");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s);
 }

 IEnumerable<string> test()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine($"called {i+1} a");
        yield return "a";
        Console.WriteLine($"called {i+1} b");
        yield return "b";
        Console.WriteLine($"called {i+1} c");
        yield return "c";
    }
 }
```

This prints

```
 called 1 a
 called 1 b
 called 1 c
 called 2 a
 called 2 b
 called 2 c
 called 3 a
 called 3 b
 called 3 c
 called 4 a
 called 4 b
 called 4 c
 called 5 a
 called 5 b
 called 5 c
 called 6 a
 called 6 b
 called 6 c
 called 7 a
 called 7 b
 called 7 c
 called 8 a
 called 8 b
 called 8 c
 called 9 a
 called 9 b
 called 9 c
 called 10 a
 called 10 b
 called 10 c
 obs done
 a
 b
 c
 a
 b
 c
 break
 here
```

But I would expect it to print something like this

```
 called 1 a
 a
 called 1 b
 b
 called 1 c
 c
 called 2 a
 a
 called 2 b
 b
 called 2 c
 c
 break
 obs done
 here
```

EDIT:
it works when I don't originally use an IEnumerable to generate the data, and add a cancellationtoken which presumably is connected to the disposal of the enumerator created by iterating .ToEnumerable...

```
 IObservable<string> str =
        test2()    
        .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("obs done"));

 IObservable<string> test2()
 {
    return Observable.Create<string>(async (observer, cancel) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !cancel.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            Console.WriteLine($"called {i + 1} a");
            observer.OnNext("a");
            Console.WriteLine($"called {i + 1} b");
            observer.OnNext("b");
            Console.WriteLine($"called {i + 1} c");
            observer.OnNext("c");
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You make a sequence observable, never Subscribe() to it, and then make it enumerable again to iterate through the results. Either take out the ToObservable and Finally, or Subscribe to the Observable. One of those might get you closer to what you're looking for. Or share more info on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @lesscode I edited with a working example, so I guess my question then is why doesn't the original `test()` get disposed if test2() gets disposed?

Comment: ok, see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
    var str =
        test()
            .ToObservable()
            .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("obs done"));
    str.Take(5).Subscribe(
        Console.WriteLine, 
        () => Console.WriteLine("break"));
```

UPDATE:
OK, I see what you're getting at. I think what you're seeing in your original example is that the default scheduler for `ToObservable` is effectively `CurrentThread`. This causes the iteration loop to block the current thread until it's iterated through the entire sequence. You can provide a different `Scheduler` to `ToObservable` (eg `Default`), which would be the equivalent of your second example.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand now. It worked as originally expected by using `.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)`.